# Visual Studio stuck in loading a project when not connected to company's network

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual Studio solution which initially came from the company's VSTS Git  repo. The solution contains multiple projects including web and webapi projects. They use the local web server and local SQL Server.
When I am not connected to my company's network, Visual Studio 2017 gets stuck while loading one of the projects. I went through the *proj files and didn't see anything referencing something outside my local paths. I turned off NuGet's checking for downloading missing packages or trying to download packages as one of NuGet's sources is a company server.

I am unable to find the reason why VS gets stuck. While being stuck and I connect to the company's network using VPN, it continues loading the projects.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this and find the cause? Can VS create some kind of a useful log file?

Comment: is the project that does gets stuck when not on vpn on a network share?

Comment: No. Everything is local.